# ¿Alguien me puede explicar como puedo hacer esto en Python?

Tags: python, base-de-datos, while

Por ejemplo, cuando escribo una materia, supongamos que es Matemáticas, ¿Dónde puedo hacer que se almacene? ¿necesito una base de datos?.
Y también tengo otro “problema”, donde pide el número de tareas que tiene y por ejemplo pongo 2, y al momento de mostrar las tareas que tiene, solo aparece el nombre de una.
El código que tengo hasta el momento es el siguiente; estoy trabajando en donde dice “Anotar tareas”.
Psdt: aun estoy aprendiendo a programar.

```
print("=======================================")
print("\n ADMINISTRADOR DE TAREAS ESCOLARES \n")
print("=======================================")

nombre = input("¿Cual es tu nombre?: ")
decision = int(input(nombre + """, ¿Qué deseas hacer? (presiona el numero correspondiente)
1.- Anotar tareas.
2.- Revisar tareas pendientes.
3.- Revisar las tareas ya realizadas: """))
if decision == 1:
    contador = 1
    num_totm = int(input("Escriba la cantidad de materias que desea almacenar: "))
    while num_totm >= contador:
        nom_materi = input("Dime el nombre de esta materia: ")
        contador+=1
    tareas = input("¿De que materia tienes tarea?: ")
    if tareas == tareas:
        contador2 = 1
        num_tareas = int(input("¿Cuantas tareas tienes?: "))
        while num_tareas >= contador2:
            titulo = input("Titulo de esta tarea: ")
            contador2+=1
fecha = input("Fecha de entrega: ")
print("Tienes tarea(s) de", tareas, "y son ", num_tareas, " tarea(s), las cuales tienen el titulo de ", titulo)
if decision == 2:
    print("a")
          
print("Fin")
```

Comment: Considera centrar tu pregunta en un problema específico, te invito a que leas [ask]

Comment: Hay preguntas que deberías ser capaz de responder tú mismo. Si sólo tienes una variable llamada `titulo` para guardar el nombre de la tarea, ¿cómo esperas que se guarde dos nombres? Cuando asignas el segundo nombre, se pierde el primero. Te aconsejo que estudies cómo se usan las listas en python.

Comment: Okey, ya veo; gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En cuanto a cómo tener persistencia de los datos, es probable que lo más como te sea usar una bbdd de este estilo https://tinydb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ . Es mucho más fácil y como de tratar con esta que ponerte a usar una bbdd de verdad.

Por otro lado si al final del todo quieres mostrar todas las tareas , tendrás que guardarlas en una lista. Y recorrer dicha lista para mostrarlas...

Como apunte, he visto otra cosa rara en el código y es cuando en un if evalúas si tareas== tareas, no se con qué finalidad quieres hacer eso, pero simplemente que sepas que eso siempre dará True .